# Cross Apply LINQ-TO-SQL

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

There are following tables:

```
create table Table_A (
    Id int primary key identity,
    Status int not null
)

create table Table_B (
    Id int primary key identity,
    Value varchar(80) not null
)

create table Table_C (
    Id int primary key identity,
    Time datetime not null
)
```

I would like to write the following query in LINQ-to-SQL using lambda notation:

```
 select * from TABLE_A a
 cross apply (
    select top 1 c.Time from TABLE_B b
    inner join TABLE_C c on c.Id = b.Id
    where b.Id = a.Id
    order by c.Time asc
 ) d
 where a.Status = 10 and d.Time > '2021-03-09'
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how it is translated by LinqToSql, but modern LINQ providers like `EF Core` and `linq2db`, should translate this LINQ query to CROSS APPLY.

```
var date = new DateTime(2021, 03, 09);

var query =
    from a in db.TABLE_A
    from d in (
            from b in db.TABLE_B
            join c in db.TABLE_C on b.Id equals c.Id
            where b.Id = a.Id
            orderby c.Time
            select new { b, c }
        ).Taske(1)
    where a.Status == 10 && d.Time > date
    select new { a, d.b, d.c };
```

Comment: EF Core 5 does not translate it like this any more. It converts to ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY and times out on all of these queries that run fine in LinqPad (and produce CROSS APPLY)

Comment: Well, it is it's optimization. And probably wrong in this case.